# Transferring training data from matlab to tensorflow

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, semantic-segmentation

I have used MATLAB's Image Labeller App to create PixelLabelData for 500 images.  So, I have got the original images and class labels for each image. This information is stored in a gTruth file which is in .mat format. I want to use this  dataset for training a Unet in tensorflow (Google Colab).

I could not achieve the training task on MATLAb because of system limitations (insufficient RAM and no GPU).However, I have read that we can import training data from MATLAB for use in Colab. So, I uploaded original image set, the labelled pixels, and corresponding mat file (gTruth.mat) on Google Drive and then mounted the drive onto the Colab environment. But I don't know how to proceed forward with the mat file in Colab.

Comment: What did you try, and what error did you encounter?

Comment: I have edited the question for more clarity and given an image link which shows the code.

Answer (score 0):

The pixelLabelTrainingData function will allow you to obtain two separate datastores for the input and pixel labeled images.

```
[imds,pxds] = pixelLabelTrainingData(gTruth);
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pixellabeltrainingdata.html

Given those, you can write each image, labeled image to parallel directories using the same naming convention using imwrite with the image file format of your choice.

```
inputImageDir = 'pathOfYourChoice';
count = 0;
while hasdata(imds)
    img = read(imds);
    fname = sprintf('img%d.png',count);
    name = fullfile(inputImageDir,fname);
    imwrite(img,name);
end
```

From there, you should be able to use standard tensorflow tooling (e.g. Dataset) to read in directories of images.